# Floor/Ceil in nvarchar sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a situation where I have a field name `Price3` and its type is `nvarchar(50)`. Now when I fetch the field I need to apply `floor/ceil` to get the expected output.

**Input**          ->   **Output** 
EUR 123        ->   EUR 123.00
EUR 123.1223   ->   EUR 123.12
EUR 123.1267   ->   EUR 123.13

There are multiple currency associated with Price3 field means EUR is not static

I tried `select SUBSTRING(Price3, 0,CHARINDEX ('.', Price3)+3)as Price3`

Comment: A prime example that the correct data type should be used from the beginning. However, if your currency always is EUR or a limited set of currencies, you can replace the currency with empty string and then cast the result to a correct data type so you can use your floor/ceil operations on that result

Comment: There are multiple currency associated with Price3 field. @AllanS.Hansen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all currencies devide with value by space. Then this example works

```
DECLARE @price3 NVARCHAR(50)
SET @price3 = 'EUR 123.9238'
SELECT 
  LEFT(@price3, CHARINDEX(' ', @price3)) + '->' + CAST(
    ROUND(
      CAST(
        RIGHT(@price3, LEN(@price3) - CHARINDEX(' ', @price3)) AS MONEY
      ),
      2
    ) AS NVARCHAR
  )
```

Comment: When we set @price3 = 'EUR 123' I want output 'EUR 123.00'

Comment: You can use format strings to get what you want or Cast as money instead float

Answer (score -1):

**MS SQL 2012 (And Higher)**

You can use a `CONVERT` or `CAST` after getting the `SUBSTRING` along with `CONCAT` and to get the desired output.

```
DECLARE @value4 varchar(50)='EUR 123';
SELECT CONCAT('EUR ',CONVERT(numeric(10,2),SUBSTRING(@value4,5,LEN(@value4)-3)));
```

[image]

**MS SQL SERVER (Older than 2012)**

Since `CONCAT` function is not available.You will have to manually `CAST` or `CONVERT` it and then append it using the +.

```
DECLARE @value varchar(50)='EUR 123';
SELECT 'EUR '+ CAST(CONVERT(numeric(10,2),ROUND(SUBSTRING(@value,5,LEN(@value)-3),2)) as VARCHAR(50));
```

[image]

Comment: how can I convert the string to numeric 'EUR 123' ? How will you manage currency code ?

Comment: @MannanBahelim Updated my answer

Comment: 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: @MannanBahelim It is in 2012+ and the question have sql server 2012 tag https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx. Atleast do a google search before making a comment.

Comment: @MannanBahelim I have updated my answer with solution for other versions of SQL Server as well.

Comment: @Jigarb1992 Did you try this?

Comment: Yes, still not good. you have hard coded the currency code(EUR) that I don't need, because it may be any currency code. But I appreciate your help. Thank you @JibinBalachandran